# Upgrade to EF Core 2.0: System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Id' cannot be configured as 'ValueGeneratedOnUpdate'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I am upgrading an Asp.Net Core 1.1 application to Asp.Net Core 2.0.

I am getting a common error in all my Entity Framework 2.0 queries:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Id' cannot be 
configured as 'ValueGeneratedOnUpdate' or 'ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate'
because the key value cannot be changed after the entity has been 
added to the store.
```

This error is obtained with the following query:

```
var themes = await _context.Themes.ToListAsync();
```

Where Theme entity is the following:

```
public class Theme
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public String Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; }
} // Theme
```

And its configuration the following:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Theme>(b => 
    {
        b.ToTable("Themes");

        b.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        b.Property(x => x.Id).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();

        b.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired(true).HasMaxLength(200);

        b.HasIndex(x => x.Name).IsUnique();
    });
}
```

And on the project Startup I have the following:

```
services.AddDbContext<Context>(x => x.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

I tried with different queries and entities and I keep getting this error.

What am I missing?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error based on above code.

Comment: I am trying to isolate the problem ...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question you have trouble to set up a auto increment for your `Id` property.

Just remove the line `b.Property(x => x.Id).UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();` and `b.HasIndex(x => x.Name).IsUnique();` because `HasKey` will already set up auto increment. For further information you could read this [MS docs article - Keys (primary)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys).
I removed the table mapping too, because of *table name pluralization* is activated by default.

Your `OnModelCreating` should be like followed:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<Theme>(b => {

        b.HasKey(x => x.Id);

        b.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired(true).HasMaxLength(200);
    });
}
```

Only for readability I would prefer following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    var themeEntity = builder.Entity<Theme>();

    themeEntity.HasKey(x => x.Id);

    themeEntity.Property(x => x.Name)
        .HasMaxLength(200)
        .IsRequired(true);
}
```

A better way would be to extract entity configuration into own classes they implementing `IEntityTypeConfiguration<T>` ([configuration separation](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api)).